# Generalized variance of a multivariate normal without calculating determinants

Tags: variance, multivariate-normal-distribution, numerics, determinant

In order to calculate ‘generalized variance’ of a multivariate normal distribution, it is often recommended (e.g., here: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat505/lesson/1/1.5) to calculate the determinant of the covariance matrix. For large covariance matrices, however, it is often impossible to calculate the determinant, or even log-determinant, because of underflow. Therefore I would like to know if it possible to approximate generalized variance of a (highly) multivarite normal without calculating determinants.

Comment: The literal generalization of the one-dimensional variance to multi-variate data is the trace of the covarince matrix, which is more efficient (and robust) to compute than hte determinant. See this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/278909/244807

Comment: Thanks! The problem is, as the next answer in that thread notes, is that, "If you need a measure of overall variance which is large when your variables are independent from each other and is very small when the variables are highly correlated, you can use the determinant of the covariance matrix". Geometrically, I need a robust measurement of a volume of a cloud of points. This volume can be very small in the degenerate case where variances are high but variables are highly correlated.

Comment: Does the minimum covariance determinant help in your case? https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07045 There are several fast algorithms available for its computation, e.g. one in the R package *DetMCD*.

Comment: @cdalitz, this is an interesting method, thanks! Unfortunately, it seems to involve the calculation of the determinant of the covariance matrix of at least half of the observations at each step, which in my case will also lead to underflow.